get only ssid from output = subprocess.check_output(list_networks_command, shell=True, text=False)
I made a code in python that give me all the available networks:
# importing the subprocess module

import subprocess

list_networks_command = 'nmcli -f SSID dev wifi list'

# Execute the command and capture the result.

output = subprocess.check_output(list_networks_command, shell=True, text=True)
output = output.replace(" ", "-")

# Print the output, all networks in range.

print(output)

the output:
enter image description here
the problem is that i want to print for example only the network:"OnePluse 5T".
how can i do this if after the network name there are spaces and i don't want the spaces after the network name, I just want the network name.
please help me
i try to make a list and to get to the first item but it give me also the spaces after the network name

Here is a function that only returns the SSIDs of available WiFI-networks:
def get_wifi_networks():
    try:
        # run the nmcli command and capture its output
        result = subprocess.run(['nmcli', '-f', 'SSID', 'dev', 'wifi', 'list'], capture_output=True, text=True)
        output = result.stdout.split('\n')
        # remove everything except the SSIDs from the output
        ssids = [line.split()[-1] for line in output if line.strip() and line != 'SSID']
        return ssids
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return []


Hi, thenk you for your reply. it give me error: File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['iw', 'dev', 'wlan0', 'scan', '|', 'grep', 'SSID']' returned non-zero exit status 1. –

My bad... the iw command needs sudo access. Your approach with using nmcli would be a better option. But in order to return only the SSIDs you could try cleaning your output like this:
output=output.stdout.split('\n')
ssids=[line.split()[-1] for line in output if line.strip() and line != 'SSID']
the "ssids" variable should now contain a list of only the SSIDs of all the available wifi-networks.
